# How to get the combinations between 2 columns in 2 different tables excluding combinations between values in each column using SQL Server 2016/17?

Tags: sql, combinations, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I am wondering how to get the combinations between 2 columns in 2 different tables excluding combinations between values from Table1 and between values from Table2 using SQL Server 2016 or 2017?

I need to combine id2 from Table1 and id from Table2.

To get the result I use this query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT id2 AS col FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT id AS col FROM Table2
)
SELECT c1.col, c2.col 
FROM CTE c1 
CROSS JOIN CTE c2 
WHERE c1.col < c2.col
ORDER BY c1.col, c2.col
```

### Table1

```
|id |id2|  
| 1 | 1 |  
| 2 | 2 |
```

### Table2

```
|id |  
| 3 |  
| 4 |
```

### Expected Result

```
|id |id2|  
| 1 | 3 | - correct combination  
| 2 | 3 | - correct combination  
| 1 | 4 | - correct combination  
| 2 | 4 | - correct combination
```

### Wrong Result

```
|id |id2|  
| 1 | 3 | - correct combination  
| 2 | 3 | - correct combination  
| 1 | 4 | - correct combination  
| 2 | 4 | - correct combination  
| 1 | 2 | - incorrect combination from Table 1  
| 3 | 4 | - incorrect combination from Table 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would appear to want:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
     Table2 t2;
```

I don't know why you are combining all ids into a single result set and then doing a cross join on that.  The results appear to be based on a simple `CROSS JOIN`.